# How to solve this "TypeError: print() argument after * must be an iterable, not int"?

Tags: python

Here is My code:-

class Solution:
def allPairs(self, A, B, N, M, X):
# Your code goes here

```
    s = set()
    for i in range (0, N):
        s.add(A[i])
  
    
    for j in range (0, M):
        if ((X - B[j]) in s):
            return ((X - B[j]), A[j])
```

Link of the Given Problem:-
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-all-pairs-whose-sum-is-x5808/0/?track=md-hashing&batchId=144

Comment: Is there anything else in the code file? E.g. showing how the code is being executed?

Comment: Just a guess: since the word "all" is in the name, should `allPairs()` return a list? Currently it is returning a single pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing because you are returning only one pair, not all pairs.
Also, X - B[j] should be equal to A[j]. So the other element you are returning should be B[j], not A[j].

Try this:

```
def allPairs(self, A, B, N, M, X):
    s = set()
    for i in range(0, N):
        s.add(A[i])

    ans = set()
    for j in range(0, M):
        if (X - B[j]) in s:
            ans.add((X - B[j], B[j]))

    return ans
```

Comment: You Can Try through that link. It show again Error

Comment: Yeah I tried and it's working for me. But I didn't use oop. Maybe the problem is because you are not declaring object properly? And if you're not using oop, just remove 'self' for the function parameters